# C++: expression must have class type with unordered_map

Tags: c++, class, priority-queue, unordered-map, std-pair

I am trying to build a priority queue of pairs with type `<string, int>`. I have a dictionary file of strings that I am using and then calculating an edit distance for these strings. I am building the queue just fine, but the issue is that if there are any duplicate strings in the file, it will create two instances in my queue, and this will be a problem for my ultimate goal. To get around this, I thought I might put the values into an unordered_map, and then into a pair. Here is my code

```
class CompareDist
{
public:
    bool operator()(pair<string, int> n1, pair<string, int> n2)
    {
        return n1.second > n2.second;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<string> words;
    vector<string> dictionary;
    unordered_map<string, int> no_dupes;
    priority_queue<pair<string, int>, vector<pair<string, int>>, CompareDist> distances;

    //there is some other code up here that is not important

    for (int k = 0; k < dictionary.size(); k++)
    {
        int edit_distance = computeEditDistance(words[j], dictionary[k]);
        no_dupes[dictionary[k]] = edit_distance;
        distances.push(make_pair(no_dupes[dictionary[k]].first, 
            no_dupes[dictionary[k]].second));
    }
}
```

I get an "expression must have class type" error when trying to use no_dupes[dictionary[k]].first and .second. It does seem sloppy, but I'm not sure how else to make a pair of the key and value of my unordered_map. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: First of all you need two loops, one to put into the map and make it all unique (why not simply [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) the vector and calling [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) to remove duplicates?) and another loop to push into the queue. Because right now you can still push duplicates. Then for your problem: `no_dupes[dictionary[k]]` is not a pair! It's a single `int` value.

Comment: How do you expect this code to compile? You have `computeEditDistance(words[j], dictionary[k])`, but you haven't defined `j`. Come to think of it, your code makes little sense overall. What, exactly, are you trying to build here?